# How would I read the txt file and output it to the console in java?

Tags: java, ascii-art

I want to output the `level1.txt` file to the console, but store it in a char array, so that I can change the color of certain icons when it outputs, so `#` would be brown as an example, My issue is that I can't even output the string, from the scanner, any tips or fixes I can implement?

Also, I would want to be able to implement a `x` and `y` axis for the player to move on the `txt` map, but I don't know how to implement that either.

Here is the code for `game.java`:

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class game {
    // change weapon to have its own file for certain weapons,
    // make at least 5 different ones with different atributes
    public static String weapon = "fists";
    public static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static char levelLoader[] = new char[100000];
    public static String level = "";
    public static File file = new File("level1.txt");

    private static void healthBar() {
        System.out.println(color.GREEN_BOLD_BRIGHT + "Health: " + color.RESET +
            color.RED + player.maxHealth + "/" + player.health +
            color.RESET + color.GREEN_BOLD_BRIGHT + " XP: " + color.RESET +
            color.YELLOW + player.maxXp + "/" + player.xp +
            color.RESET + color.GREEN_BOLD_BRIGHT + " Weapon: " + color.RESET +
            color.CYAN + weapon + color.RESET);
    }

    // starts up game and tells player how to move
    public static void intro() {
        try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
        System.out.println("You can move by either pressing W, A, S, D or " +
                "type 'exit' to close the game, your character is the @ ");
        startUp.slow();
        try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
        player.initializePlayerAtributes();
    }

    public static void paitWalls() {
    }

    //prints game board to terminal
    public static void paintGameBoard() throws FileNotFoundException {
        healthBar();

        Scanner levelReader = new Scanner(file);
        level = levelReader.nextLine();
        while(levelReader.hasNextLine()) {
            level = level + "\n" + levelReader.nextLine();
        }
        levelLoader = level.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i > levelLoader.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(levelLoader[i]);
        }
        levelReader.close();
    }

    // uses w a s d and exit to determine if to move or exit
    public static void playerMovementAndExit() {
        String movementOrPause = s.nextLine();
        switch (movementOrPause.toLowerCase()) {
            case "w":
                player.y++;
                try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
                break;
            case "s":
                player.y--;
                try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
                break;
            case "d":
                player.x++;
                try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
                break;
            case "a":
                player.x--;
                try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
                break;
            case "exit":
                try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) {}
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("You need to move with W A S D or" +
                        " type 'exit' to close");
                startUp.slow();
                try {startUp.clear();} catch(Exception e) { }
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void run() {
        intro();
        while(true){
            try {paintGameBoard();} catch (Exception e) {}
            playerMovementAndExit();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `level1.txt` file:

```
#########################################
#.........#.........#...................#
#...................#...................#
#.........#.........#...................#
###############...###...................#
#.........#.........#...................#
#.......................................#
#.........#.........#...................#
#########################################
```

Comment: Please check this out for first part of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151714/reading-text-file-into-a-char-array-in-java and

Comment: i cannot tell if the comment cuts off after "and"

Comment: It cuts after "and". Weird thing is i didn't add "and". Now i am not able to edit it.

Comment: i finally figured out the problem in the first place, after having the program throw a FileNotFoundException, i discovered the file wasn't even linked properly to the program lol.